# Future methods do not support parameter type of Map<Id,SObject>

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, callout

I am calling a method from a trigger that makes an external rest api post call.  I am creating my json like this and trying to use the setBody() method, but getting an error and I am not sure how to resolve it.

The error is:

> Future methods do not support parameter type of `Map<Id,SObject>`

I tried to play around with the way I was generating the json using the generator, but to no avail.

```
 @future (callout=true)
 public static void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {

 Opportunity oldOpp = (Opportunity) oldItems.get(oppId);
 Opportunity newOpp = (Opportunity) newItems.get(oppId);

 Map<String, Object> obj = new Map<String, Object>();
 obj.put('customer_id', newOpp.customer_id__c);
 obj.put('location_id', newOpp.location_id__c);

 String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(obj);

 String endpoint = 'https://xxxxxx/api/v2/xxxx';
 Http h = new HTTP();
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
 req.setBody(jsonBody);
 req.setMethod('POST');
 req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
 HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Future methods only accept [Apex primitive values and collections of primitives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm) as parameters. They do not support sObject parameters or complex parameters including sObjects.

The easiest way to correct this is to break your code into a synchronous piece and pass only the serialized JSON to your `@future` method:

```
 public static void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {

 Opportunity oldOpp = (Opportunity) oldItems.get(oppId);
 Opportunity newOpp = (Opportunity) newItems.get(oppId);

 Map<String, Object> obj = new Map<String, Object>();
 obj.put('customer_id', newOpp.customer_id__c);
 obj.put('location_id', newOpp.location_id__c);

 String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(obj);

  AfterUpdate.makeCallout(jsonBody);
}

@future (callout=true)
public static void makeCallout(String body) {

 String endpoint = 'https://xxxxxx/api/v2/xxxx';
 Http h = new HTTP();
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
 req.setBody(jsonBody);
 req.setMethod('POST');
 req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
 HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use another form of asynchrony that supports sObject parameters: Queueable Apex.

Comment: does this mean the response from the api call has to be handled in the makeCallout() method @david-reed?

Comment: @user1669296 Yes.